# How do I subtract only the time in my javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to subtract the time of period 8 to 7.
I originally got this code from chat gpt but needed to rewrite everything so im trying to learn now so this may not make since due to me being a newbie

```
const periods = [
  { time: 9.11, name: "advisory" },
  { time: 9.57, name: "second period" },
  { time: 10.48, name: "third period" },
  { time: 11.39, name: "fourth period" },
  { time: 12.30, name: "fifth period" },
  { time: 13.05, name: "lunch" },
  { time: 13.56, name: "sixth period" },
  { time: 14.47, name: "seventh period" },
  { time: 15.40, name: "eighth period" }
];
```

console.log(periods[8] - periods[7])

As I stated i'm new to this and don't know if there is a way to only get the time so i can do the math.

I tried doing periods.time but that didn't work. I have basically 0 clue how I could do this
I read some documentation on w3schools but I still couldn't understand. If you could help explain this would be very helpful.

Comment: convert times to minutes, then convert back

Comment: Well, it would be `periods[8].time`, but if those are supposed to be hours and minutes, you can't handle time that way.  9.57 is NOT the same as 9 hours and 57 minutes.  10.50 would be 10 hours and 30 minutes (half an hour).

Comment: going back to look at this to learn more this makes a lot of sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create functions to convert the Number to a number of minutes, and a number of minutes to a Number where the decimal represents minutes

There's probably 100 different ways

Here's one

```js
const periods = [
  { time: 9.11, name: "advisory" },
  { time: 9.57, name: "second period" },
  { time: 10.48, name: "third period" },
  { time: 11.39, name: "fourth period" },
  { time: 12.30, name: "fifth period" },
  { time: 13.05, name: "lunch" },
  { time: 13.56, name: "sixth period" },
  { time: 14.47, name: "seventh period" },
  { time: 15.40, name: "eighth period" }
];

const timeToMinutes = (time) => time * 100 - Math.floor(time) * 40;
const minutesToTime = (minutes) => (minutes - minutes % 60) / 60 + (minutes % 60) / 100;
const answerInMinutes = timeToMinutes(periods[8].time) - timeToMinutes(periods[7].time)
console.log(minutesToTime(answerInMinutes))
```

Comment: Ok thank you for letting me know cause I did test so, yes I'll need to convert them to time so thank you so much